# AngularJS; Send a function from the parent into directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a reusable component/widget as a directive using a template and isolated scope. I'd like to be able to also send a callback into the directive and call it in the widget. Is this possible?
Something like...

mainView template:
`<my-widget callback="someFunction"></my-widget>`

directive:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        callback: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/partials/widget.html',
}
```

And the template:

```
<input type="text" ng-change="callback()" />
```

So when the widget value is changed, it triggers the callback function that was passed in the main view

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how we did it.

Comment: you should use callback : '&' instead of '='

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `&`. [Quoting the old angular docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/guide/directive): "& or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope".

Try this as your directive code:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        callback: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: '/partials/widget.html',
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but I'm now getting: http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile:ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange

Comment: it works fine if I use ng-init="callback()" but it can't do ng-change

Answer (score 0):

You can also $watch for it in the link or controller.

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) { {
      scope.$watch(attrs.myDirective, function(value){ ... });
    }
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to do as suggested and use an & rather than an =, but also this still wouldn't work until I added ng-model as well to my input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myValue" ng-change="callback()" />
```